# node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/lib/create-icon-set.js: #<WeakSet> could not be cloned

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I'm using "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0", and I got this error `node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/lib/create-icon-set.js: #<WeakSet> could not be cloned.` with iOS, any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: same issue any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried with different versions sets and found working versions.

```
...
"react-native": "0.63.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
...
```

Hope this works fine.

Comment: I got this error in Android also but anyway, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that is related to the babel.
By default, we are using

```
"@babel/core": "7.14.0",
"@babel/runtime": "7.14.0",
```

these versions. But we need to downgrade to

```
"@babel/core": "7.12.17",
"@babel/runtime": "7.12.18",
```

versions.

Downgrading to these versions will solve the problem.